# Javascript compare start time and end time onchange() to ensure valid

Tags: javascript, validation

I have been testing this in jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work. Basically I am trying to validate starttime and endtime everytime one of those dropdowns is changed, which should call the function checktime() which will see if the start time is after the end time, otherwise an error message appears. I have the following HTML code with the two drop downs to select a start time and end time:

```
<form id="my_form">
<dd><label for="Record_Start_Time">Start Time:</label>
<select name="Record_Start_Time" id="Record_Start_Time" onchange="checktime()">
<option selected value="0800">0800 - 8:00 am</option>
<option  value="0830">0830 - 8:30 am</option>
<option  value="0900">0900 - 9:00 am</option>
<option  value="0930">0930 - 9:30 am</option>
<option  value="1000">1000 - 10:00 am</option>
<option  value="1030">1030 - 10:30 am</option>
<option  value="1100">1100 - 11:00 am</option>
<option  value="1130">1130 - 11:30 am</option>
<option  value="1200">1200 - 12:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1230">1230 - 12:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1300">1300 - 1:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1330">1330 - 1:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1400">1400 - 2:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1430">1430 - 2:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1500">1500 - 3:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1530">1530 - 3:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1600">1600 - 4:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1630">1630 - 4:30 pm</option>
</select></dd>
<dd><label for="Record_End_Time">End Time:</label>
<select name="Record_End_Time" id="Record_End_Time" onchange="checktime()">
<option selected value="0830">0830 - 8:30 am</option>
<option  value="0900">0900 - 9:00 am</option>
<option  value="0930">0930 - 9:30 am</option>
<option  value="1000">1000 - 10:00 am</option>
<option  value="1030">1030 - 10:30 am</option>
<option  value="1100">1100 - 11:00 am</option>
<option  value="1130">1130 - 11:30 am</option>
<option  value="1200">1200 - 12:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1230">1230 - 12:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1300">1300 - 1:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1330">1330 - 1:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1400">1400 - 2:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1430">1430 - 2:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1500">1500 - 3:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1530">1530 - 3:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1600">1600 - 4:00 pm</option>
<option  value="1630">1630 - 4:30 pm</option>
<option  value="1700">1700 - 5:00 pm</option>
</select></dd>
 </form>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
function checktime(){
//start time
var start_time = $("#Record_Start_Time").val();
//end time
var end_time = $("#Record_End_Time").val();
//by this you can see time stamp value in console via firebug
console.log("Time1: "+ start_time + " Time2: " + end_time);

if(start_time > end_time) {
$("#start_time").after('<span class="error"><br>Start-time must be smaller then End-   time.</span>');
$("#end_time").after('<span class="error"><br>End-time must be bigger then Start-time.</span>');
    return false;
}
```

When I run the code I see the following errors in my console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Uncaught ReferenceError: checktime is not defined

Obviously there is something wrong with my syntax, I just can't see it so some fresh eyes probably won't hurt. I could also be going about this entirely wrong and should just be checking onsubmit instead of onchange. Help/Suggestions anyone?

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dUe83/13/

Comment: Your javascript should have another '}' at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/6H4b7/2/

There were several problems with your code:

1. Missing `}` in the end of the code.
2. Incorrect ids for the elements: `start_time` instead of `Record_Start_Time` and `end_time` instead of `Record_End_Time`.
3. And you should use `window.checktime = function() {...}` instead of `function checktime() {...}` in JSFiddle, because it warps your code into dummy function and your functions are considered local. By using `window.checktime = function() {...}`, you are making it global.

Comment: Damn... knew I forgot to rename something. Thanks for the suggestion about window.checktime

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications on your jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dUe83/15/

```
$(function(){
function checktime() {
    //start time
    var start_time = $("#Record_Start_Time").val();
    //end time
    var end_time = $("#Record_End_Time").val();
    //by this you can see time stamp value in console via firebug
    console.log("Time1: " + start_time + " Time2: " + end_time);

    if (start_time > end_time) {
        $("#start_time").after('<span class="error"><br>Start-time must be smaller then End-time.</span>');
        $("#end_time").after('<span class="error"><br>End-time must be bigger then Start-time.</span>');
        return false;
    }}});
```

You forgot one "}" at the end and the $() stuff